# Send an array using javascript to Spring controller

Tags: javascript, spring

I´m making a call using javascript and I would like to send an array:

```
var selected = [];
selected=getAllEnginesIdsSelected();
    console.log("selected: "+selected);
    $.getJSON('/call/' + selected,
            function(myList) {
```

Console.log retrieves selected: 2,5

In MVC Controller I have

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/call/{selected}")
public List<List<myList>> myCall(@RequestParam(value="selected[]") String[] selected){
```

I gives an error. I don´t want to use AJAX. This is posible to send?

**EDIT**

The funcion that I use in Javascript to retrieve array is:

```
function getAllEnginesIdsSelected() {

        var selected = [];

        $("input:checkbox[id^='engine_']:checked").each(function(){
            var ele=$(this)[0].id;
        });

        return selected;

    }
```

Comment: What's the error are you getting ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/myapp/call/2,5 ERROR 400

Comment: Obviously there is no such url, Hence it throws 400 error. Then where did you use the javascript code with getJSON etc ?

Comment: I made an Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `@PathVariable` instead of `@RequestParam` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the request parameters you send to spring controller by using:

```
@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams
```

You need to assign a name to each parameter to retrieve them later:

```
?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

Another way is to serialize your data and send a POST request to the controller.